# asp.net web service executed more than one time

Tags: asp.net, web-services, asmx

I have a web service .asmx that I call from an android mobile application. it return a random number to the android application, and send the same number using sms.

My problem that some times the web service is executed more than one time in the same time and returning the same random number. so the sms is sent more than one time all in one request.

I have two files one is the one I call from my app getRandomNumber.asmx and the second is getRandomNumber.cs the file that generate the number, save to the database and send it by sms.

so i put a log file in both files and waited to the duplicate to show.

this is from a log file I made to track this issue:

Time: 2014/05/24 06:41:46 - user: 610410 - random: Going IN 
Time: 2014/05/24 06:41:46 - user: 610410 - random: Going IN 
Time: 2014/05/24 06:41:46 - user: 610410 - random: Going IN 
Time: 2014/05/24 06:41:46 - user: 610410 - random: Going IN 
Time: 2014/05/24 06:41:49 - user: 610410 - random: 853967 
Time: 2014/05/24 06:41:49 - user: 610410 - random: 853967 
Time: 2014/05/24 06:41:49 - user: 610410 - random: 853967 
Time: 2014/05/24 06:41:49 - user: 610410 - random: 853967

what is the cause and how to solve it.

**UPDATE: Code added**

getRandomNumber.asmx.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Services;
using System.Web.Script.Services;
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;
using OracleDataAccessLayer; 


namespace MobileWebServices
{
[WebService(Namespace = "http://www.example.com")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
[System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]


[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]

public class getRandomNumber : System.Web.Services.WebService
{
    [WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true, ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
    public string sendRandomNumber(int UserNumber)
    {
        Logger.logError("Time: " + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss") + " - user: " + UserNumber + " - random: Going IN");
        return Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new getRandomNumber().sendRandomNumber(UserNumber));
    }
}
}
```

getRandomNumber.cs

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;

namespace OracleDataAccessLayer
{    
public class getRandomNumber : OracleDataAccessLayer.MobileDataAccess.OracleCommandLibrary
{
    string sql = "";
    public getRandomNumber() { }
    string GeneratePasscode(int PasscodeLength)
    {
        string _allowedChars = "123456789";
        Random randNum = new Random();
        char[] chars = new char[PasscodeLength];
        int allowedCharCount = _allowedChars.Length;
        for (int i = 0; i < PasscodeLength; i++)
        {
            chars[i] = _allowedChars[(int)((_allowedChars.Length) * randNum.NextDouble())];
        }
        return new string(chars).PadRight(PasscodeLength, '0').ToString();
    }
    public string sendRandomNumber(int parUserNumber)
    {
        string random = "0";
        string mobile="";
        try
        {

                string randomNum = GeneratePasscode(6);
                Logger.logError("Time: " + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss") + " - user: " + parUserNumber + " - random: " + randomNum);

                //select the mobile number and the language
                sql = "SELECT C.COUNTRY_LANG, MOBILE " +
                      "FROM COUNTRY_MASTER_TABLE C " +
                      "JOIN USER_REG_MASTER U ON " +
                      "C.COUNTRY_CODE = U.NATIONALITY_NO " +
                      "WHERE U.UNO = " + parUserNumber;
                DataTable lang = Retrievedata(sql);

                if (lang.Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    sql = "INSERT INTO SMS_SEND " +
                          "(SMS_ID, USER_NUMBER, SMS_DATE, RANDOM, DEVICE_TYPE) VALUES " +
                          "(SEQ_RANDOM.NEXTVAL, " + parUSERNumber + ", SYSDATE, " + randomNum + ", 1)";

                    if (ExecuteTransactions(sql) > 0)
                    {
                    mobile = lang.Rows[0].ItemArray[1].ToString();
                            // check the lang Arabic, Non Arabic
                            // if arabic convert to hex

                            if (lang.Rows[0].ItemArray[0].ToString() == "A")
                            {
                                messageOrg = "الرجاء استخدام الرمز " + randomNum;
                                Byte[] stringBytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(messageOrg);
                                StringBuilder sbBytes = new StringBuilder(stringBytes.Length * 2);
                                foreach (byte bb in stringBytes)
                                {
                                    sbBytes.AppendFormat("%{0:X2}", bb);
                                }
                                message = sbBytes.ToString();
                                messageHex = message;

                            }
                            else
                            {
                                // If english do nothing
                                messageOrg = "Please use this code:  " + randomNum;
                                message = "Please use this code:  " + randomNum;
                            }

                            // add the message and mobile number to SMS service provider URL and create HttpWebRequest

                            string url = "http://www.example.com/Send.aspx?MOBILENO=" + mobile + "&MESSAGE=" + message + "&rest of prams";
                            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
                            request.Method = "GET";

                            // execute request and get response back
                            using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
                            {
                                Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
                                StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
                                smsSequence = reader.ReadToEnd();
                                reader.Close();
                                dataStream.Close();
                            }

                            // check if success get the response and check id number and insert into SMS_SENTBOX for logging
                            int success = 0;
                            if (smsSequence.Substring(0, 3) == "+OK")
                            //if (Int32.TryParse(smsSequence.Substring(7, smsSequence.Length - 7), out success))
                            {
                                random = randomNum;
                                sql = "INSERT INTO SMS_SENTBOX " +
                                      "(SMS_SENT_SEQUENCE, USER_NUMBER, EVENT_DATE, EVENT_TIME, USER_MOBILE, EVENT_TYPE, SENT_DATE, SMS_TEXT, SMS_TEXT_DUMP)" +
                                      "VALUES " +
                                      "(1, " + parUserNumber + ", SYSDATE, TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'HHMI'), " + mobile + ", 'random', SYSDATE, '" + messageOrg + "', '" + messageHex + "')";
                                try
                                {
                                    ExecuteTransactions(sql);
                                }
                                catch (Exception e)
                                {
                                }
                            }
                    }
                }

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Logger.logError(e.ToString() + "\n");
            throw e;
        }
        return random;
        /**/
    }
}
}
```

thankyou

Comment: Please add the code to your question. It's almost impossible to diagnose it from the currently provided information.

Comment: This is **NOT** WCF.  ASMX is legacy technology (its the pre-WCF way of doing SOAP web services in .NET) and should not be used.  In any event, ASMX != WCF.  I have updated your tags accordingly.

Comment: Thank you for the information I just received the code and I'm not that familiar with .net web services.

is there is a way I can fix it without the need to rewrite it?

Comment: Where is the calling code. It seems that there is the problem from my POV.

Comment: the web service is been called from an android app. if there is more than one request the web service should return different random numbers not the same and the log file will be something like this
Time: 2014/05/24 06:41:46 - user: 610410 - random: Going IN
Time: 2014/05/24 06:41:47 - user: 610410 - random: 753889 
Time: 2014/05/24 06:41:47 - user: 610410 - random: Going IN
Time: 2014/05/24 06:41:48 - user: 610410 - random: 126985

Comment: @PatrickHofman your were right it's from the calling code.

Answer (score 0):

From your description, I don't quite understand whether you have a single problem (the same random number is generated multiple times) or two problems (same random number and request is sent multiple times).

Anyhow, the source of your problem is described in Microsoft's documentation about the [Random() constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h343ddh9.aspx):

> The default seed value is derived from the system clock and has finite
>   resolution. As a result, different Random objects that are created in
>   close succession by a call to the default constructor will have
>   identical default seed values and, therefore, will produce identical
>   sets of random numbers.

To fix it, create a single static instance of `Random`:

```
static Random random = new Random();

....

string GeneratePasscode(int PasscodeLength)
{
    string _allowedChars = "123456789";
    char[] chars = new char[PasscodeLength];
    int allowedCharCount = _allowedChars.Length;
    for (int i = 0; i < PasscodeLength; i++)
    {
        chars[i] = _allowedChars[(int)((_allowedChars.Length) * random.NextDouble())];
    }
    return new string(chars).PadRight(PasscodeLength, '0').ToString();
}
```

Comment: My problem is I send one request to the web service, it get executed multiple times, generating the same random number, saving it to the database multiple times and sending it by sms multiple times. I will change the random to static and test it. Thank you

Comment: It is suppose to execute one time per request.

Comment: Thank you. The problem is from the android side but your answer helped me figured it out